# Set minimum amount to in the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this input field where I want to add the minimum amount for the user to enter if minimum amount is Rs. 100, so the user should not enter amount less than that. I tried using min but it still getting redirected to other page on submit. Also I am restricting the user to enter first digit as 0. The script validation for numeric value is working fine. But the problem is user can not type the number with the right side key available in the keyboard. Below is the code I have tried so far. Please help me find my mistake.

HTML CODE:

```
<input type="text" class="input_style" maxlength="6" min="100" id="stamp_amount" name="answer[28]" placeholder='Minimum Rs. <%= @service.min_stamp %> ' required/>
```

JS CODE:

```
    $("#stamp_amount").keydown(function (e) {
       // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
       if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && ( e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true ) ) || 
         // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
       }

       if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8) {
        // let it happen, don't do anything

       }
       else {
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
          if ((event.keyCode !==9) && (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 )) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }   
        else{

          if($.trim($(this).val()) =='')
        {
            if(event.keyCode == 48){
            event.preventDefault(); 
            }
        }

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not regular expression allowing only numbers and check on the input value?

Comment: Or just HTML5 input works fine accepting only numbers and a minumum value of 100.. https://jsfiddle.net/htaLn9eg/1/

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried HTML5 input type number?

```
<input type="number" value="100" min="100"/>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: I don't want to use input type number. I have used validation for numeric values. I have tried using value="100" min="100" it still goes to another page on submit

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 $(document).keydown(function (e) {console.log(e.keyCode)});
```

Just to see if the keyCodes are the same, for me they are.

Comment: if I am using this code it is working but without that it doesn't